# Cornered arrow in a division

Tags: css, css-shapes

I wanted to create something like a arrowed representation for a map, for which I am going to use the **RickMarker Google API** support. But I wanted to achieve something like the image below in CSS.

[image]

If it would not be feasible, please explain why and alternative method.

Comment: [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/5wL57/) is the closest that I could achieve with only CSS. But frankly, for complex shapes I would recommend using images rather than CSS.

Comment: @Harry You have achieved it to the closest. I just need a proof of concept. Can you please make it a answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Caution:** This answer is only to illustrate that achieving this shape is possible (albeit, with a complicated approach). Please do not use CSS for such complex shapes. You would be better off using PNG files.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, white 90%, #444 91%, #98CC2D 91.5%, #777 94%, #98CC2D 94.5%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, white 90%, #444 91%, #98CC2D 91.5%, #777 94%, #98CC2D 94.5%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 90%, #444 91%, #98CC2D 91.5%, #777 94%, #98CC2D 94.5%);
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-right: 2px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
  top: 87.5%;
  left: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: white;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 40px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 168px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>Test bubble</div>
```

**Browser Compatibility** - Tested in Chrome v24, Firefox v19, Safari v5.1.7 (on Windows).

**Final Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in css. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I think your best option would be to just use the image you provided here, and remove the white background parts that you don't need using gimp or photoshop. Then you should save the file with `.png` extention. This will preserve the transparent background.

If you can do this in css I would love to hear it to!